# App Crashes on iPad 1 but not iPad 2 or 3rd Gen

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, ios-simulator

I am currently working on an enterprise App being distributed via Ad Hoc. We have tested the app on the iPad 2 and 3rd Gen and it works fine and also in the simulator but on the clients iPad 1 it is constantly terminating.

iOS Version 5.1.1
Xcode Version 4.4.1

The iPad 2+3 have more Ram and CPU power could this be what causes the app to terminate.

Are there any ways to check for this ? / optimise the App to work properly with the iPad 1.

Any suggestions seems to be a really unusual error. Is there anyway to make the simulator behave like an iPad 1.

Comment: Can you get a crash report? Lack of RAM is quite likely.

Comment: Signature issues? Really just a guessing game..

Comment: Thanks for the crash report suggestion @Thilo unfortuantly I don't have access to the iPad 1 device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does sound like you've got memory problems. Have you tried running your app in Instruments and looking at the memory allocation / leaks? This will give you an idea of where you can reduce your memory footprint.

Obviously your memory requirements depend on the app, but for some kind of data driven app (not a game) I'd probably be looking to keep my allocation under say 10 MB.

Testing your app in Instruments should **always** be a part of your workflow (as should compiling with warnings as errors and the static analyzer on).

Comment: Thanks for your help the real memory usage was 237MB and all allocations was around 110MB. Clearly the iPad is near the limit of its memory. Working now to reduce the amount of memory it uses.